# C# simulating a global scope to contain user-defined but runtime-constant delegate arrays

Tags: c#, delegates, environment-variables, global

I have some delegates, two classes and a struct that look kind of like this:

```
delegate Value Combination(Value A, Value B);

class Environment
{
    private Combination[][] combinations;
    private string[] typenames;
    private getString[] tostrings;

    public Environment() { ... } //adds one 'Null' type at index 0 by default
    public void AddType(string name, getString tostring, Combination[] combos) { ... }

    public Value Combine(Value A, Value B)
    {
        return combinations[A.index][B.index](A, B);
    }
    public string getStringValue(Value A)
    {
        return tostrings[A.index](A);
    }
    public string getTypeString(Value A)
    {
        return typenames[A.index];
    }
}

class Container
{
    public string contents
    {
        get
        {
            return data.text;
        }
    }
    public string contentType
    {
        get
        {
            return data.type;
        }
    }

    private Value data;

    public Container(Value val)
    {
        data = val;
    }

    public Container CombineContents(Container B)
    {
        return new Container(data.Combine(B.data))
    }
}

struct Value
{
    public string type
    {
        get 
        {
            return environment.getTypeString(this);
        }
    }
    public string text
    {
        get 
        {
            return environment.getStringValue(this);
        }
    }

    public readonly int type;
    public readonly byte[] raw;
    public readonly Environment environment;
    public Value(int t, byte[] bin, Environment env)
    {
        type = t;
        raw = bin;
        environment = env;
    }

   public Value Combine(Value B)
   {
       return environment.Combine(this, B)
   }
}
```

The reason for this structure is that Containers can have Values of various types, which combine with each other in user-defined ways according to the current Environment (which, like Container and Value, is differently named so as to avoid conflicting with the System.Environment class in my actual code- I used the name here to concisely imply its function). I cannot get around the problem with subclasses of Value and generic Containers since values of different types still need to be combinable, and neither Container nor the base Value class can know what type of Value combination should return.

It doesn't seem possible to define the Environment class in a global way, as the existing System.Environment class doesn't seem to allow storing delegates as user variables, and giving it a static method returning an instance of itself would render it unmodifiable*, and would require a new instance of the class to be created every time I want to do anything with Values, which seems like it should be a huge performance hit.

This causes two problems for me:

- There is an extra reference padding out all my Values. Values are variable in size, but `raw` is almost always 8 bits or less, so the difference is significant, especially since in actual implementations it will be fairly common to have several million Values and Containers in memory at once.
- It is impossible to define a proper 'null' Value, as a Value must have an Environment in it and the Environment must be mutable. This in turn means that Container constructors that do not take a Value as an argument are much more convoluted.

The only other way around this I can think of would be to have a wrapper class (either an extension of Environment or something with an environment as a parameter) which is required in order to work with Containers or Values, which has all extant Containers and Values as members. This would solve the 'null' problem and neaten up the Value class a bit, but adds a huge amount of overhead as described and makes for a really convoluted interface for the end user. Those problems are, with a good deal of work and some changes in program flow, solvable as well, but by that point I'm pretty much writing another programming language which is far more than I should need.

Is there any other workaround for this that I'm missing, or am I mistaken about any of my disqualifying factors above? The only thing I can think of is that the performance hit from the static implementation might be smaller than I think it would be due to cacheing (I cannot perform realistic benchmarking unfortunately- there are too many variables in how this could be used).

---

*Note that an environment doesn't strictly speaking need to be modifiable- there would be no problem, technically, for example, with something like

```
class Environment
{
    private Combination[][] combinations;
    private string[] typenames;
    private getString[] tostrings;

    public Environment(Combination[][] combos, string[] tnames, getString[] getstrings)
    {
        combinations = combos;
        typenames = tnames;
        tostrings = getstrings;
    }
}
```

except that this would be much more awkward for the end user, and doesn't actually fix any of the problems I've noted above.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want a singleton.

Comment: A singleton would work, though it is not strictly necessary. C# lacks support for them in any case, it seems.

Comment: C# supports the singleton pattern just fine.

Comment: You can read about c# singleton here:http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: You say "It doesn't seem possible to define the Environment class in a global way, as the existing System.Environment class doesn't seem to allow storing delegates as user variables" --- What bearing does System.Environment have on your problem or solution?

Comment: @PoulBak the problem with that resource is that the solutions contained within all rely either on the static-method-calls-constructor method I describe above or don't allow the user to modify the environment in any way, requiring that they create their own Environment class, which requires they create their own Value class, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble trying to understand exactly what you were trying to achieve here! So apologies if I'm off the mark. Here is a singleton based example that, if I understand the problem correctly, may help you:

```
public class CombinationDefinition
{
    public string Name;
    public getString GetString;
    public Combination[] Combinations;
}

public static class CurrentEnvironment
{
    public static CombinationDefinition[] Combinations = new CombinationDefinition[0];
    public static Environment Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }

    static ThreadLocal<Environment> _instance = new ThreadLocal<Environment>(() =>
        {
            Environment environment = new Environment();

            foreach (var combination in Combinations)
                environment.AddType(combination.Name, combination.GetString, combination.Combinations);

            return environment;
        });

    public static Value CreateValue(int t, byte[] bin)
    {
        return new Value(t, bin, Instance);
    }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
CurrentEnvironment.Combinations = new CombinationDefinition[]
{
    new CombinationDefinition() { Name = "Combination1", GetString = null, Combinations = null },
    new CombinationDefinition() { Name = "Combination2", GetString = null, Combinations = null },
};

Value value = CurrentEnvironment.CreateValue(123, null);
string stringValue = CurrentEnvironment.Instance.getStringValue(value);
```

Important to note - `CurrentEnvironment.Combinations` must be set before the Environment is used for the first time as accessing the `Instance` property for the first time will cause the Environment to be instantiated by its `ThreadLocal` container. This instantiation uses the values in `Combinations`to use the existing `AddType` method to populate the Environment.

Comment: Huh, that does work. In fact it behaves exactly how I wanted it to behave! I was under the impression that you couldn't assign to static fields, but it seems I was mistaken. Thank you very much, I will have to look more into the ThreadLocal object in the future, it seems quite useful!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make `Environment` a "Singleton" (recomended), or mark everything inside it as `static`.  Another possibility is to use an IoC container, but that may be more advanced than you are ready to go for at this point.

The Singleton pattern usually declared a `static` `Instance` property that is initialized to a new instance of the class through a private constructor.  All access is done through the `static Instance` property, which will be available globally. You can read more about Singletons in C# [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

`static` will allow you to access the members without instantiating an instance of the class and it will act as a "global" container.

Singleton Example:

```
class Environment
{
    private static Environment _instance;
    public static Environment Instance
    {
        get
        {
             if (_instance == null)
             {
                   _instance = new Environment();
             }
             return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Environment(){}

    private Combination[][] combinations;
    private string[] typenames;
    private getString[] tostrings;

    public Environment() { ... } //adds one 'Null' type at index 0 by default
    public void AddType(string name, getString tostring, Combination[] combos) { ... }

    public Value Combine(Value A, Value B)
    {
        return combinations[A.index][B.index](A, B);
    }
    public string getStringValue(Value A)
    {
        return tostrings[A.index](A);
    }
    public string getTypeString(Value A)
    {
        return typenames[A.index];
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Environment.Instance.getStringValue(this);
```

Please excuse any syntax errors in code, I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment.

Comment: You clearly did not read the entire question. I mention exactly the method you use in your above implementation and explain why I cannot use it.

Comment: I just read your question again, and I don't see anything about why this isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: The user, who cannot modify the Environment class themselves, cannot change anything about what `new Environment()` does. `Value.Combine()` would only have access to the default methods instantiated by `new Environment`, not to the user-defined functions they actually need.

Comment: Have you considered the factory pattern, similar to the singleton, but taking an initialization action as an argument?  Factory instantiates the class and executes the custom action on it. allowing the user to run whatever initialization code they need.

Comment: I don't see how that could help on its own, the method would still be called from `Value.Combine()` which doesn't know anything about the user defined methods.